# Take a file name and read the contents of that file into 2 lists

Tags: python

I have defined 2 lists and I want to read the contents of a text file into the 2 lists shown below. I can't work out how to structure the code so that the names and numbers from the text file are called into the lists?

```
def read_file(filename, player_names, player_scores):

    infile = open("high_scores.txt", "r")

    infile.close()
```

defined lists

```
player_names = ["","","","",""]
player_scores = [0,0,0,0,0]
print('Player_names',player_names)
print('Player_scores',player_scores)
```

Comment: What's the structure of your text file? Also, try trying a bit more. You haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: what does the file look like?

Comment: Lance william 10
Fox foster 8
Phil Murray 6
Jackson Redding 1

Answer (score 1):

Consider your input file is a tab delimited of players and scores

> player1   100
>
> player2   50
>
> player3   65

your working code will be

```
def read_file(filename, player_names, player_scores):
    with open(filename, "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            player_score = line.split('\t')
            player_names.append(player_score[0])
            player_scores.append(int(player_score[1]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    player_names = []
    player_scores = []
    read_file('high_scores.txt', player_names, player_scores)
    print('Player_names',player_names)
    print('Player_scores',player_scores)
```

and this will be your output:

> ('Player_names', ['player1', 'player2', 'player3'])
>
> ('Player_scores', [100, 50, 65])